# Parsing XML without decoding Character-Entities in Attributes and Text-Nodes

Tags: java, xml-parsing, saxparser

Is there a way todo that with SaxParser or a similiar Parser ? 
Example:`<root>...<t1 value="&quot;&gt;&#x3d;x&#x20;"> &lt;&lt;&amp;</t1>..</root>`

MyXmlHandler:

```
public void startElementx(final String uri, final String localName,
        final String qName, final Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {
    if ("t1".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
        System.out.println(attrs.getValue(1));
    }
}
```

The output is [">=x] but I need the origin-value like this:

```
 [&quot;&gt;&#x3d;x&#x20;]
```

In the "characters"-method I have the same problem. I get <<& instead of

```
 &lt;&lt;&amp;
```

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

You question has nothing to do with SAXParser, I think.

You're probably looking for the [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) class

Comment: You can edit your answer to include it instead of waiting until next time.  :)

Comment: I did edit my answer to include the name of class.
Are you saying I should may be include an explanation? I mean, the answer sought was a way to do the task and the class I've mentioned provides that, right? I just didn't want to clutter the answer with so much stuff that can be found easily by googling the name of the class, which, is probably what he/she'll have to do anyway, even if I give an explanation here. And please do correct me if I am wrong. I'm new here and I'm just getting to know stuff :)